# R library(sqldf) cannot change the contain of a column with na( null)

Tags: r, sqldf

I have a column where I want to replace the null value( the column only contain na) with a value, when I use

```
library(sqldf)
options(sqldf.driver = "SQLite")
var1<-sqldf("select col1, case when col2 is \"NA\" then 'sth' else 'sth' end as col2 from table1")
```

It is not changing anything, i have also tried

```
 var1<-sqldf("select col1, case when col2 is null then 'sth' else 'sth' end as col2 from table1")
```

and simply try to replace all ( the whole column is with null):

```
var1<-sqldf("select col1, 'sth'as col2 from table1")
```

Not of these work, in order to get it work I have to create a new column like

```
var1<-sqldf("select col1, 'sth'as col2_sth from table1")
```

but I need to keep the column with the new value, what can I do in this case? Is it a bug in sqldf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your column is NA, probably your problem is that the column is numeric and you can not enter characters without changing the class, see the example:

```
library(sqldf)
options(sqldf.driver = "SQLite")
table1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:6, col2 = rep(NA, 6))

sqldf("select col1, case when col2 is NULL then 'sth' else 'sth' end as col2 from table1")
  col1 col2
1    1   NA
2    2   NA
3    3   NA
4    4   NA
5    5   NA
6    6   NA
Warning message:
In asfn(rs[[i]]) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Changing the class of col2 this works without problems.

```
table1$col2 <- as.character(table1$col2)
sqldf("select col1, case when col2 is NULL then 'sth' else 'sth' end as col2 from table1")
  col1 col2
1    1  sth
2    2  sth
3    3  sth
4    4  sth
5    5  sth
6    6  sth
```